# Are questions regarding gardening tools off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

I just read through the FAQ and it looks to me that, technically, if I were ask questions about tools for gardening, then that would be off topic.

I'm not asking about specific brand recommendations but identification questions for odd tools.  However, if I had a garden tool and I didn't know how to properly use it, would that apply on this site?

I could probably think of a few examples but, according to the FAQ, it doesn't perfectly fit.

I would assume such questions would certainly fit the essence of the site. Could someone please clarify and possibly update the FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about tools are certainly welcome; we have a couple of (albeit low-use) general-purpose tags for them: [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and [tool-maintenance](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-maintenance).

We also have special purpose tags for a few types of tools: [string-trimmer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-trimmer), [lawn-mower](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower), [chainsaw](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainsaw).

Often, the questions aren't tagged with the name of the tool, but with the action you'd use it for. So we have [pruning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruning) instead of [pruner](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruner), [digging](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digging) instead of [shovel](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shovel), etc.

---

Updating the FAQ sounds reasonable, but given the low number of tool-related questions that we've had in the lifetime of the site, I'd be inclined to make it more general. Perhaps something like:

> the practice of gardening, including timing, tools and techniques.

Comment: I agree.  The problem is, there are many "picky" people who like to point out that people don't "perfectly" meet the faq.  I've been on StackExchange for years.  I hate getting downvotes after 2 years because some user can't see the forest for the proverbial trees.

Comment: I'll wait for a while to see if there are any comments or suggestions for improvement on the FAQ wording.

Comment: @RLH I'm a fairly picky person regarding what is on/off topic, but I definitely think there is a place for questions on tool maintenance/use/choices. This is information that that has to do with gardening directly. You can't garden without tools of some kind.

Comment: I agree with you JMusser...tools are such a big deal!!!  Without tools, gardening wouldn't even be in the dictionary.